# Zend ViewHelper Sub Functions

Tags: php, function, zend-view, zend-framework, view-helpers

I want to add more than one function to a ViewHelper. Usually there is one function named like the class and like the file name.

How can I add several functions into one ViewHelper?

E.g. like this:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyMenuHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function Horizontal($parameter)
    {
         return "...";
    }
}
```

`echo $this->MyMenuHelper()->Horizontal($parameter);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex was on the right path, but missed something in his answer: the actual `myMenuHelper()` method has to return the view helper itself, for this to work:

```php
class Zend_View_Helper_MyMenuHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function myMenuHelper()
    {
        return $this;
    }

    public function horizontal() { ... }

    // more methods...
}
```

And then, as mentioned:

```php
echo $this->myMenuHelper()->horizontal();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you don't want to pass through the main method of a view helper, although it's not that bad for *some* kinds of logic. In that case, use `getHelper()`:

```
class Zend_View_Helper_MyMenuHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function myMenuHelper()
    {
        // some logic, maybe the main one
    }

    public function horizontal() 
    {    
        // some other logic
    }
}
```

The following examples bypass `myMenuHelper()` completely:

```
// in controller
$this->view->getHelper('MyMenuHelper')->horizontal();

// in view
$this->getHelper('MyMenuHelper')->horizontal();`
```

In some cases for example, I populate the view helper with some internal data *in the controller*, the call its main method directly *in the view*, which acts on that data.

```
// in controller
$this->view->getHelper('MyMenuHelper')->storeData($someArray);

// in view
$this->myMenuHelper(); // iterates over $someArray
```

Answer (score 0):

try to start the function name with a lower case letter

```
        class Zend_View_Helper_MyMenuHelper extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
        {
                public function horizontal($parameter)
                {
                       return "...";
                }
        }
```

in the view:

```
        echo $this->myMenuHelper()->horizontal($parameter);
```

Comment: Error `Call to a member function horizontal() on a non-object [in view script]`